# Load image into div depending on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a page with a number of thumbnail images. When a user clicks on one of the thumbnail images then the larger version of that image loads into a div. The JQuery that I have used to do this is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.sigProBettonLink').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href'),
    image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = function () {
    $('.itemImage').empty().append(image);
    };
    image.onerror = function () {
      $('.itemImage').empty().html('That image is not available.');
    }
    $('.itemImage').empty().html('Loading...');
    return false;
  });
});
```

I want to keep this functionality but add to it. I have set the site up so that the URL page can have a number of variables depending on how the user got to that page. For example

```
http://www.mysite/mypage?image=1
http://www.mysite/mypage?image=2
http://www.mysite/mypage?image=3
```

Basically, if the URL is **http://www.mysite/mypage?image=1** then I want the first image to load (as if the user has clicked on the first thumbnail). If the URL is **http://www.mysite/mypage?image=2** then I want the second image to load in the div (as if the user had clicked on the second thumbnail) and so on..

Comment: use switch and location.search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Marc Audet for poitning me in the right direction.

I have modified your code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("image1") > -1) {
        var urlvalue = $('a.sigProBettonLink').get(0);
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("image2") > -1) {
        var urlvalue = $('a.sigProBettonLink').get(1);
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("image3") > -1) {
        var urlvalue = $('a.sigProBettonLink').get(2);
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("image4") > -1) {
        var urlvalue = $('a.sigProBettonLink').get(3);
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("image5") > -1) {
        var urlvalue = $('a.sigProBettonLink').get(4);
    }
    else if (window.location.href.indexOf("image6") > -1) {
        var urlvalue = $('a.sigProBettonLink').get(5);
    }
    image = new Image();
    image.src = urlvalue;
    image.onload = function () {
        $('.itemImage').empty().append(image);
    };

    $('a.sigProBettonLink').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        image = new Image();
        image.src = url;
        image.onload = function () {
            $('.itemImage').empty().append(image);
        };
        image.onerror = function () {
            $('.itemImage').empty().html('That image is not available.');
        }
        $('.itemImage').empty().html('Loading...');
        return false;
    });

});
```

This now works perfectly. Thank you so much to everyone for your help with this :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case You need to parse the URL.
The following snippet will parse each parameter and store the array as a variable:

```
var vars = [], hash;
    var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
}
```

Now You can test if 'image' is set or not and decide what to do

```
var image = '';
if( typeof vars["image"] != "undefined" ){
    //set
    image = vars["image"];
}else{
    //not set
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Oh , misunderstood.

You don't need the document.URL but the link href.

```
$('a.sigProBettonLink').click(function () {

   var vars = [], hash;

   //Clicked img url
   var q = $(this).attr('href'); // <----------------

    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
    }


    image = new Image();

    if( typeof vars["image"] != "undefined" ){

        //set the image url You will to load
        image.src = q;

    }else{
        //not set
        image.src = ' default url ?';
    }

    image.onload = function () {}
    ...


});
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer works but how can I add my click function to it so that if the url is http://www.mysite/mypage?image=1 it fires the function?

Comment: Is this method for parsing the URL equivalent to the Example 6 in the MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Example_.236.3A_Get_the_value_of_a_single_window.location.search_key.3A ? Your approach is much easier to understand than the regular expression used in the MDN example.

Comment: @DesignSubway I think you need to incorporate pszaba's URL parsing code into the jQuery that I show in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the prototype code for an approach using jQuery:

As a demo, I used the following HTML snippet:

```
<a class="sigProBettonLink" href="http://placekitten.com/50/100">Image 1</a><br>
<a class="sigProBettonLink" href="http://placekitten.com/100/100">Image 2</a><br>
<a class="sigProBettonLink" href="http://placekitten.com/150/100">Image 3</a>

<div class="itemImage"></div>
```

and here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    if (pathname.contains("image1")) {
        var urlvalue = $('a.sigProBettonLink').get(0);
    }
    if (pathname.contains("image2")) {
        var urlvalue = $('a.sigProBettonLink').get(1);
    }
    if (pathname.contains("image3")) {
        var urlvalue = $('a.sigProBettonLink').get(2);
    }
    image = new Image();
    image.src = urlvalue;
    image.onload = function () {
        $('.itemImage').empty().append(image);
    };

    $('a.sigProBettonLink').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        image = new Image();
        image.src = url;
        image.onload = function () {
            $('.itemImage').empty().append(image);
        };
        image.onerror = function () {
            $('.itemImage').empty().html('That image is not available.');
        }
        $('.itemImage').empty().html('Loading...');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Use `window.location.pathname` to get the URL and then use the native JavaScript `.contains()` method to check for the image name.

The demo code is at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/sdQTv/

To see the functionality work, try: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/sdQTv/show/image2

You may have to tweak the parsing if you are using a name-value pair in the URL (`?image=1`).

For information and examples about parsing the URL, see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

However, this example illustrates the basic approach.

Comment: Thank you Marc, you have REALLY helped me. I have modified your answer slightly and submitted my own answer to my question. Thanks once again, you are a star!

Comment: Glad to help! An up vote would be appreciated.  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

`$(location).attr('href')` gives you the current URL